# Having a little Bash trouble

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.pdf; do verapdf -f 1a --success --format html *.pdf > KONTROLL/$i"_check.html"; 
done

exit 0
```

The code above is testing PDF-files in the current directory for compliance to PDF/A-1a. The successful result generates a report that will be presented in HTML-format. I try to redirect this report to an individual file per PDF - named "tested_file_name_check.html". However the result is that the first tested PDF-file, say file1.pdf, is tested and the report gets stored as KONTROLL/file1.pdf_check.html. So far so good. Then the next one, file2.pdf, has its report added to KONTROLL/file1.pdf (so that file grows) and there is an empty KONTROLL/file2.pdf_check.html created - size 0 bytes.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Many thanks in advance:-)

/Paul

Comment: You forgot to change `*.pdf` to `$i` in the verapdf command.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$i` instead of `*.pdf` in the command.

**edit** like this:

```
for i in *.pdf
do
   verapdf -f 1a --success --format html $i > KONTROLL/$i"_check.html"
done
```

Comment: I thing you should repeat it from the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow but it seems you found the reason. Thank you very much.